# Flutter : Why can't I move the cursor in the TextField to the beginning of the text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `TextField` widget. After filling it out, I Have Tried to move the cursor to the beginning of the text, but I could not do that.

The cursor stops after the first letter, not before.

Is the reason that the text is in **Arabic** which is right to left writing language?

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try adding: autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always to your TextFormField.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried maybe setting `TextField(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl)` ? It might solve your problem as it's supposed to be used when you write text right to left.

Comment: True, but the problem appears when writing text from left to right or numeric numbers, and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Directionality class in your code like this

```
new Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: TextField(
     textAlign: TextAlign.right,
     controller: _textEdittingControler_bookName,
     autofocus: true,
     decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "افزودن کتاب",
                hintText: "نام کتاب را وارد کنید"
                ),
     )
```

Refer documentation for more info about [directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) class